# Implement method of lines to solve PDE in Python scipy with comparable performance to Matlab's ode15s

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, numerical-methods, differential-equations

I want to use the method of lines to solve the [thin-film equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_equation). I have implemented it (with `gamma=mu=0`) Matlab using `ode15s` and it seems to work fine:

```
N = 64;
x = linspace(-1,1,N+1);
x = x(1:end-1);
dx = x(2)-x(1);

T = 1e-2;
h0 = 1+0.1*cos(pi*x);

[t,h] = ode15s(@(t,y) thinFilmEq(t,y,dx), [0,T], h0);

function dhdt = thinFilmEq(t,h,dx)
    phi = 0;
    hxx = (circshift(h,1) - 2*h + circshift(h,-1))/dx^2;
    p = phi - hxx;
    px = (circshift(p,-1)-circshift(p,1))/dx;
    flux = (h.^3).*px/3;
    dhdt = (circshift(flux,-1) - circshift(flux,1))/dx;
end
```

The film just flattens after some time, and for large time the film should tend to `h(t->inf)=1`. I haven't done any rigorous check and convergence analysis, but at least the result looks promising after only spending less than 5 mins to code it.

I want to do the same thing in Python, and I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi

def thin_film_eq(t,h,dx):
    print(t)   # to check the current evaluation time for debugging
    phi = 0
    hxx = (np.roll(h,1) - 2*h + np.roll(h,-1))/dx**2

    p = phi - hxx   
    px = (np.roll(p,-1) - np.roll(p,1))/dx       
    flux = h**3*px/3        
    dhdt = (np.roll(flux,-1) - np.roll(flux,1))/dx

    return dhdt

N = 64
x = np.linspace(-1,1,N+1)[:-1]
dx = x[1]-x[0]

T = 1e-2
h0 = 1 + 0.1*np.cos(np.pi*x)

sol = spi.solve_ivp(lambda t,h: thin_film_eq(t,h,dx), (0,T), h0, method='BDF', vectorized=True)
```

I add a `print` statement inside the function so I can check the current progress of the program. For some reasons, it is taking very tiny time step and after waiting for a few minutes it is still stuck at t=3.465e-5, with dt smaller than 1e-10. (haven't finished yet by the time I finished typing this question, and it probably won't within any reasonable time). For the Matlab program, it is done within a second with only 14 time steps taken (I only specify the time span, and it outputs 14 time steps with everything else kept at default). I want to ask the following:

1. Have I done anything wrong which dramatically slows down the computation time for my Python code? What settings should I choose for the `solve_ivp` function call? One thing I'm not sure is if I do the vectorization properly. Also did I write the function in the correct way? I know this is a stiff ODE, but the ultra-small time step taken by
2. Is the difference really just down to the difference in the ode solver? `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(f, method='BDF')` is the recommended substitute of `ode15s` according to the official `numpy` [website](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html). But for this particular example the performance difference is one second vs takes ages to solve. The difference is a lot bigger than I thought.
3. Are there other alternative methods I can try in Python for solving similar PDEs? (something along the line of finite difference/method of lines) I mean utilizing existing libraries, preferably those in scipy.

Comment: Try using [`odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html).  It doesn't have as many features as the newer `solve_ivp`, but it tends to be faster.  It still probably won't be as fast as Matlab, however.

Comment: FYI: Here's an example that uses the method of lines with SciPy and odeint: https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/KdV.html

Comment: There is another example of using odeint with the method of lines in the SciPy tutorial: [Solving a system with a banded Jacobian matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html#solving-a-system-with-a-banded-jacobian-matrix).

Comment: The central difference quotient has the denominator `2*dx`, in the current form you have an additional factor 4. This can be interpreted as a change in the time scale, your solution evolves 4 times as fast as the solution of the original PDE.

Comment: Did you try the other methods, esp. Radau, RK45 and, in the most recent version of scipy, DOP853? There can be extreme differences in the number of function calls, with the winner in least calls depending on the problem.

Comment: It looks like there  is something wrong with vectorized= True. With false I get 22 evaluations (12.7ms for the whole evaluation), with numba applied on the function (which would give can give a high performance benefit on a more computationally expensive function (`@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",cache=True)`) it takes 3.27ms.

Comment: @max9111 I tried setting `vectorized=False` and it does run a lot faster. Can you elaborate a bit more about the numba? Do I just `import numba as nb` and add the decorator right above the function `thin_film_eq`? It gives `TypingError: Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.roll' or unsupported use of the function.`